# XMLHttp request cannot load [link].Redirect from [link] to has been blocked by CORS policy in laravel 5

Tags: ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am getting this error in `laravel 5`.I have added `CORS` as per this link  http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/ but still getting the following error.All other solution tried but did not work.

> XMLHttp request cannot load [link].Redirect from [link] to [link] has been
>   blocked by CORS policy.No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested source.Origin [link] is therefor not allowed
>   to access in laravel 5.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't really help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Condier this link [here](http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/)

Comment: @PrashanthBenny even I tried the same link

Answer (score 0):

With the security reasons, browser is blocking different domain transfer. You can use [CORS in Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) to fix this.

Further you can use Chrome extension [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)(for testing) which is somehow not restricted by [this policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html).

Comment: Thank yo for your reply.But I solved my problem by changing absolute URL to relative.So now it is working